# First time using R: How can I compare two columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset "world" with a column "women09" that contains percentage values and a column that "pr_sys" that contains "yes" or "no". I need to find the percentage of "women09" that are "yes" and "no". I don't how to compare the two columns

```
women09 = world[["women09"]]
pr_sys = world[["pr_sys"]]
wpr = ifelse(pr_sys = "Yes",count.fields(women09))
```

> Error in ifelse(pr_sys = "Yes", count.fields(women09)) :
>
> unused argument (pr_sys = "Yes")

```
ifelse(pr_sys="Yes",wpr=women09,0)
```

> Error in ifelse(pr_sys = "Yes", wpr = women09, 0) :
>
> unused arguments (pr_sys = "Yes", wpr = women09)

Data:

```
dput(world[1:64, c("women09", "pr_sys")])

w <- structure(list(women09 = c(NA, NA, 20.5, NA, 18.5, 8.3, 20.8, 
NA, NA, NA, 25, NA, NA, 18.1, 0.9, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 18.6, NA, 10.5, NA, NA, 4.3, 4.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12, NA, 
19, NA, 7, 10.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8.4, 3, NA, 8.9, NA, 15.2, 
10.8, 30, 10.7, NA, 18.2, 3.8, NA, NA, 16.4, NA, NA, 4, 13.2),
pr_sys = c("No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", NA, NA, "No", NA, "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", NA, "No", "No", NA, "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", 
"No", NA, "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -64L))
```

Comment: It would help greatly if you posted (part of) your data. Try `dput(world[, c("women08", "pr_sys")])`, and add the output to your question.

Comment: It would also help to indicate the expected output, as it currently not very clear what you want to do. It sounds like you just need to count yes/no in the `pr_sys` column, but then you talk about comparing columns.

Comment: the conditional operator for equality is `==` (not `=`).

Comment: Your `dput` output is incomplete.

Comment: @taylor112 not sure the question makes sense. could you please clarify? You already have the percents in the column "pr_sys", so what is the goal?

Comment: I fixed the `dput()` output so it will create a `data.frame` when we run it. Probably it was too big so printing cut it off. When that happens you can select only the top few rows by using `head()`, f.ex. like so: `head(world[, c("women09", "pr_sys")], 20)`, or use the row index: `world[1:20, c("women09", "pr_sys")]`. In both cases only the first 20 rows are returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
install.packages("tidyverse"); library(tidyverse) #since you said you're new to R
world <- as.data.frame(
  list(women09 = c(NA, NA, 20.5, NA, 18.5, 8.3, 20.8),
       pr_sys = c("No", "Yes", "No", "Yes","Yes", "No", "No"))
  )

world %>%
  group_by(pr_sys) %>%
  summarize(tot = sum(women09, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
pr_sys   tot
<fct>  <dbl>
1 No      49.6
2 Yes     18.5
```